# Как записать уникальное пустое значение

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

База данных Postgresql

Сделал 2 уникальных колонок 
первый поставил numeric
второй text

там должны быть 2 айди

первый это id пользователя в другой базе только число (например: 4665, 221, 99851)

второе это id пользователя в своей базе (пол m,w + номер регистрации + год регистрации) w4532018

практический все пользователи уже повторяются в базах есть некоторые которые есть либо у меня либо в другой базе

то есть надо записать в уникальные поля значения которые повторяются (null)
чтобы можно было найти пустые

записывал на php

```
$ids[] = "(NULLIF('$oldID','')::integer, '$newID')";

$ids = implode(",", $ids);

$ids_insert_query = "INSERT INTO public.ids (glob_id, new_id) VALUES ".$ids." ON CONFLICT (glob_id) DO NOTHING;";
```

я загружаю их с файлов json каждый месяц и могут снова отправлять тот же id на добавления

(465, m46512018) => (465, null)
если есть glob_id с таким id то пропустить но если у него нет new_id то добавить new_id

(465, m46512018) => (null, m46512018)
если есть new_id с таким id то пропустить но если у него нет glob_id то добавить glob_id

(465, m46512018) => (465, m46512018)
если повторяются оба то пропустить

помогите как правильно сделать 
sql плохо знаю

выдает ошибку что повторяются значения

```
pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint &quot;ids_new_id_key&quot;
```

Как добавить null в колонку с уникальным индексом с помощью php
(несколько null)

[image: Скриншот базы данных]

первая колонка уникальная но туда можно несколько раз добавить null

как добавить тоже самое с помощью php

```
INSERT INTO public.ids
(glob_id, new_id) VALUES 
(7233, 'm8702018'),
(NULL, 'w4562018'),
(NULL, 'm7532018') 
ON CONFLICT (glob_id) DO NOTHING;
```

вот это как выполнить с помощью PHP glob_id это строка как его привести в NULL

Comment: UNIQUE INDEX и будут только уникальные значения поля

Comment: Вы как то очень не понятно написали. 5 раз уже перечитал. Приведите пример таблицы (вот прямо как она создана create table) с имеющимися строками, несколько строк которые вы хотите добавить и что должно получиться в результате. Особенно не понятен момент, с null в одной из колонок, вам надо в БД добавить запись с null в поле id например ? а таблица это позволяет ? А то что будут несколько записей с null в колонке id это не страшно

Answer (score 0):

Я разобралься 
"NULL" нужно в виде строки отправлять,
и дубликаты были в самих id